# Extruding outwards evenly

Tags: modeling

I would like to know how to extrude with even length in all directions. When I extrude with selected faces I get some lengths higher than the others.

[image]

This is especially seen when you subdivide: 
[image]

Comment: Did you 'extrude and move on individual faces'? or did you 'extrude' on 2 axis? Also when you 'extrude and move on individual faces' you should first apply the scale and/or rotation (menu shortcut: CTRL + A).

Comment: Extruded with Alt + E -> region(vertex normals). Applying scale and rotation did not help either.

Answer (score 1):

After the extrusion you can trim the 3 axis in the toolshelf (T).

[image]

Comment: does not work when extruding along vertex normals